# controller path not found for static images? asp.net mvc routing issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an image folder stored at ~/Content/Images/

I am loading these images via

```
<img src="/Content/Images/Image.png" />
```

Recently, the images aren't loading and I am getting the following errors in my error log. What's weird is that some images load fine, while others do not load.

Anyone have any idea what is wrong with my routes? Am I missing an ignore route for the /Content/ folder?

I am also getting the same error for favicon.ico and a bunch of other image files...

```
<Fatal> -- 3/25/2010 2:32:38 AM -- System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path '/Content/Images/box_bottom.png' could not be found or it does not implement IController.
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType)
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

My current routes look like this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "ControllerDefault",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/project/{projectid}/{action}/{searchid}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Listen", action = "Index", searchid = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution, having the same prob when publishing

Answer (score 7):

I would insert another ignored route immediately under the first one.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/Images/{*pathInfo}");
```

Comment: I'm going to try this... but the prob only occurs on staging (not dev) so won't be until tomm that I can test.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at your solution explorer view, I'm guessing that your Content folder is in the root of the project along with a folder for Controllers and Views.  Trying modifying your image src as shown below...

```
<img src="../../Content/Images/Image.png" />
```

Comment: That wouldn't work for me... I need to use the root path (/Content/Images) because those images are referenced in css files that stand alone in dev, and are minified and combined in production (thus losing relative location). But why would this help anyway?

Comment: @rksprst: I've had the same issue and solved it like this. Right now `/Content/Images/Image.png` will look within your views action folder for the image...  It is not pulling from the `~/Content/Images/` folder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare less specific routes to the bottom:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    "ControllerDefault",
    "{controller}/project/{projectid}/{action}/{searchid}",
    new { controller = "Listen", action = "Index", searchid = "" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

But I don't think that this is the problem here. From the exception it seems that the web server executing this application has a wildcard mapping with the `aspnet_isapi` filter meaning that all file will be associated with the ASP.NET runtime even the static files.

Comment: Yep, you can do that little trick in IIS where you first fake the Content folder as being a virtual directory, remove the wild card mapping, then remove the Content folder as being a virtual directory. This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Image.png")%>" alt="does this work?" />
```

Comment: oops, answered with a question. -1

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;` somewhere do you?

Comment: No, I don't have that anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The exception `... could not be found or it does not implement IController` doesn't have to be in error. Actually `/favicon.ico` doesnt resolve to a controller so this means that the next module (or is it handler?) should try to handle the request. So in a way it's an "expected exception".

The problem is when this exception gets logged and clogs the logs. When using log4net, adding the following `<filter>` element to the default appender should keep it out:

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
  <regexToMatch value="System.Web.HttpException \(0x80004005\): The controller for path '[^']*' was not found or does not implement IController\." />
  <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
</filter>
```