# Image path is searching for controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

When in run the application, I get exception in **Application_Error** handler :

```
The controller for path '/Content/images/ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

Can anyone explain me, why the **Image path** is **interpreted** as **MVC Action** ?

The **MVC router** is **searching** for equivalent **controller**.

This behaviour is really wierd. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513058/controller-path-not-found-for-static-images-asp-net-mvc-routing-issue

Answer (score 2):

I think it becomes because image is not exists in your filesystem (IIS at first check file system for static content).
Try to use in global.asax routes registration next code:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("/Content/{*path}");
}
```